# switching between more than one start Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in my app :

1. Log in (I want to make it the Start activity just for the  first time I launch the app)
2. Info( after that I want to make it the Start activity for all time )

So how to handle this ?

Comment: Session Manager In Andrid Sava Id And Password In preference and check it

Answer (score 3):

use shared preferences

```
 boolean start = getSharedPreferences("User",0).getBoolean("start",true);
     if(start){
         Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Login.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
     }else{
       Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityMain.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
    }



 if(start){
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("User",0);
   Editor e = sp.edit();
   e.putBoolean("start",false);
   e.commit();
  }
```

Comment: Nice one., it helped for me

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have two activities: Login and Main.
Requirement: Show Main activity if user credentials are supplied. Show Login activity otherwise.

To implement this, we make our Login activity our main application activity. Each time application is started, it runs Login activity. Inside Login activity a sheck should be implemented to see whether user credentials are saved or not. 
If not, then Login activity allows entering login and password, and save.

If yes, then it starts Main activity via intent and finishes itself. Something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityMain.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```